# Fan Control - Toshiba Satellite e45DW -c4210

Tags: sound, fan

Fans constantly running and making a ton of noise, I tried doing sensor-detect and got this at the end:

```
Sorry, no sensors were detected.
This is relatively common on laptops, where thermal management is
handled by ACPI rather than the OS.
```

While using Windows it does not make this much noise. Can I just turn the fans down? There is no option in the bios for fan control.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I tried the drivers, and it said that my os is not compatible. I found that `indicator-cpufreq` helps, it looks like my cpu governor was set to performance, I can manually set the frequency and the laptop runs much quieter!

Answer (score 0):

This laptop comes with a Windows program called Health Monitor. When this runs it shows the CPU and GPU temperatures and the fan speed. Clearly the sensors are there, however sensors-detect can't find them.

If you are comfortable with compiling and  making programs you could try the toshiba utilities here [Toshiba Linux Utilities](http://www.buzzard.me.uk/toshiba/download.html) However as I do not have a Toshiba laptop I cannot vouch for them being safe.